# Battery powered project with multiple voltages

Tags: low-power, battery-operated

I am working on a project which requires three different voltage levels - Motor that can run at 7-12 V. Hall sensor that can run at 5-25 V. nRF24L01+ that can run at 2-3.6 V and AVR (arduino) which can run at 2-5 V.

Since battery life is a major concern, I think voltage regulators (specially the linear ones) will be a bad idea. For motor, I am planning to use a LiPo battery - 11.1 V rated. It'd be great if remaining circuit can be run on 3V. This way I can use AA cells for them. The only blocker is Hall sensor. I saw one which can run at 2.5-25 V but most of them run at 4.8-25V so I am not sure whether I'd be able to get low power version in local market.

As such, I am left with two choices:

- Use AA cells to get 3V which will take care of Arduino and nRF.
  Use boost converter to power Hall sensors.
- Use 2xAA cells to power up Arduino and nRF and another 2xAA cells
  added in series with the previous ones to get 6 V and use it for Hall
  sensor.

Which one would be a better idea?

Also, it'd be great if you can suggest me some non-latching type Hall sensors in 3 pin sil package, if possible with working voltage range starting from 1.5 or 2 volts.

Comment: What hall sensor are you looking at?

Comment: Why not use a boost regulator from the motor supply for the hall sensor AND a buck regulator for the low voltage stuff?

Comment: @Ignacio - Currently I am planning to go for W134 hall sensor in TO92 package if I can get it. Otherwise I am not sure. Probably I will pick whichever is available in local market. The only criteria is - it should be non latching type. Means it should turn ON when magnet is brought closer and turn OFF when magnet is taken away.

Comment: @Andyaka - The only reason I don't want to do it that way is power dissipation in those regulators. I have to save as much battery juice as possible. However I am not an expert. Do you think using regulators will be a good idea. I need a battery life of at least six months out of 5000 mAh battery.

Comment: Do you really think powering part of the circuit from a LiPo and the rest from AA batteries is an optimal solution?

Comment: @NickJohnson - Not in terms of total size and cost but in terms of battery life, I thought so. However feel free to change my view. I am no expert.

Comment: @Whiskeyjack You should definitely try and avoid power conversion for the motors if possible - but DC-DC switching regulators can achieve efficiencies in excess of 90%, and the draw for other components will be low compared to motor draw. There's really no need to have a secondary supply.

Comment: Also, consider how much more lithium ion battery you could fit in the space of the AAs, and how much simpler your battery management will be without it.

Comment: @NickJohnson - I gave it a thought. I saw the datasheet of LM2575 5V switching regulator. Quiescent current turns out to be around 10 mA. Had it been uA, I could have gone for it. The project I am working on is going to be a consumer project, not a hobby project. So long battery life is the biggest concern. I am not worried about motor current at all because that will be turned on only 10-20 times a day for a few ms each time - assume motor running for 5 sec per day. However uC, rf and sensors will wake up and take measurements on a regular basis - every second or so.

Comment: @Whiskeyjack There are certainly regulators with lower quiescent current than that. If the active power use is also low, you may even consider using an LDO instead. Consider how requiring multiple different types of battery looks in a consumer product!

Comment: @NickJohnson - I completely agree with you. However I got an idea. How about using 6xAA cells. I will make different combinations out of them simultaneously. One wire will come out of series 6xAA giving 9 volts. That goes to the motor. Another wire comes from (3S)P(3S) giving 4.5V. This goes to hall sensor and Arduino. Last wire comes from (2S)P(2S)P(2S) giving 3V. This goes to the nRF module. This combination will make sure all batteries are being used equally. And I will be able to use it without any regulator thereby saving my component cost. What do you say?

Comment: @Whiskeyjack You'll have difficulty getting that manufactured. By far the simplest option is to use buck and LDO regulators as needed, with low quiescent current requirements. They _do_ exist. You can also use the MCU to disable the regulators when not required.

Comment: Also, you can't simultaneously wire up all 6 batteries in series and in parallel!

Answer (score 1):

In the end, the most simple solution is usually the best. Let's try to sort your needs out.

1) You need a beefy power supply for a motor, 12V-ish. Fine, you have this sorted out already.

2) You need to power the Hall sensor. Why not power it directly from 12V, if it's 5-25V rated? There can be 2 minor difficulties there :

- Connecting Hall sensor output to mcu input. If the output is open collector, that's obviously fine as-is. Otherwise, depending on the operation frequency and the mcu input's impedance requirements, the 12v logic out -> 3.3V mcu in connection could be as simple as a large enough resistor, input is then clamped by mcu input diodes.
- Current draw from hall sensor at 12V. That's up to you to determine if it is acceptable. If you need to power it off when dot doing measurements, that's a bit more involved but can be done easily.

3) MCU power can be done simply with a 3.3V buck regulator. Google "low quiescent current buck regulator" returns LT3991 as the second hit, Iq=2.1µA for 12V->3.3V. Then it's just a matter of putting the mcu and peripherials to sleep most of the time, which you'll need to do anyway.

In the end, I think there is NO WAY a second battery with holder can be more efficient for a given battery life, be it weight-wise, volume-wise, and even price-wise, than a simple switching regulator and slightly larger main battery. The only exception I can possibly see is if you need galvanic isolation and low RFI - totally off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

If your hall-effect sensor is (are) digital (as opposed to linear), you can power it directly from the motor supply.  Current consumption is very low and most digital hall-effect sensors have an open-drain output that goes LOW when the sensor is active.

I'm assuming that your motor current is significantly higher than anything else in your system.  If it's not important that everything keeps running when the motor battery goes flat, I'd use a SMPS buck-converter to drop the motor battery down to 3.6 Vdc and run both the RF module and the AVR controller from that.

You can add a small backup battery pack that switches over automatically if you do need to keep the RF module and AVR running after the motor battery has died.  Use 4- "AA" cells in series and use diodes to sum both battery packs into the input of the buck converter.

Comment: 3.6V is a very odd voltage to run logic at. That's probably the absolute max from the NRF datasheet, and not intended to be an operating voltage.

Comment: Choose whatever voltage that you think is appropriate that will power both devices. I like to be at the high end of the range so as to maximize the dynamic range of any A/D inputs.

Comment: If you run at absolute maximum voltage, any deviation or tolerance in the regulator will put you outside the absolute maximum - not a good idea.

Comment: Even if it's important to keep mcu/communication running when the battery is "flat", you can just stop powering the motor when the battery is "nearly flat", keeping just enough juice for the mcu/communication.